# Mime Type detection of Office files is resulting in application/x-tika-ooxml

Tags: apache-tika

I am trying to detect the mime types of the file input stream.

I just have tika core in my classpath. I am using 2.0.0 version.

However for a docx file "application/x-tika-ooxml" is always detected. Office file detection is always resulting in x-tika-ooxml.

I tried wrapping the input stream in TikaInputStream also but the same result.

Below is my code

```
public class TikaTester {
        
        public static void main (String a[]) {
            
            try {
                FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/Users/<>/Downloads/Test DMS.docx");
                detectMimeType(stream);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
        
        public static void detectMimeType(InputStream stream) {
            Tika tika = new Tika();
            try {
                String mimeType = tika.detect(stream);
                System.out.println("Mime type detected " + mimeType);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This works if i add tika-parsers in the classpath and with TikaInputStream needs to be used.

May be tika core does not have the parser for office files.

Comment: That's exactly right.  You need tika-parsers on your class path so that Apache POI can open the file and identify which subtype of ooxml it is.

Comment: @TimAllison thanks for the reply...one more question i have just for my confirmation...that in default Tika config content detection always through magic bytes first and then through resource name ?

Comment: Y, and if the resource name/file extension doesn't offer a specialization of the file type detected by bytes, Tika falls back to the detection by bytes.  For example, if Tika detects a .zip file via bytes, but the file name ends in .txt, it will report .zip.  However, if the file name ends in .kmz, it should return kmz because kmz is a specialization of application/zip.

Comment: I am as also facing same issue with the office files for instance like spreadsheets where the content type is always "apache/x-tika-ooxml" instead of "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", since data for which the content type is to be determined is always obtained as stream, with no information on the extension, we cannot form the metadata object having property "RESOURCE_NAME_KEY" with filename and extension. 

I am using tika-core and tika-parsers-standard-package both of 2.1.0 versions.

Can you suggest some solution to this.